# How to automatically make array of all files in website folder?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a folder of about 100 images on my website called "IMG"
Now let's say I have a div element: `<div id="templateDiv"></div>`
Using javascript, how would I add all images from "IMG/" into that div without adding `<img src="IMG/IMGNAME.jpg">` for every image?
Sorry, I'm not very good at explaining.
Just ignore the fact that would take ages to load.

EDIT
Ok my bad explanation skills have made me change my question.
How do I automatically make array of all files in website directory?

Comment: There is no way to load images without using img tag. Each image should have img tag associated with it.

Comment: are you trying to learn to make a slider? if so, [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZO2RTMNSAY)

Comment: Ok, scratch everything I just said. Basicly I just need to get an array of all files in a websites directory.

Comment: Why can't you use `<img>`? It is the standard way to show image data in the browser. I strongly suspect your error is in trying to avoid it.

Comment: Well I need to put in 100+ images and want to swap those images out for other images so I don't want to put 100+ img elements

Comment: @Solman252 Why not use a Canvas element and `drawImage()` onto it a whole bunch of times?

Comment: @OOPSStudio I want to avoid writing a bunch of nearly identical lines of code.

Comment: @Solman252 Use a loop?

Comment: Yep, thats pretty much what I want to do, but I would need an array of all files in my dir first, so basicly my question has changed to "How to automatically make array of all files in website folder?"

Answer (score -1):

Okay, your question is incredibly unclear, but from reading all your other comments and things, it seems you simply want to get an array that contains the filename of every file in a directory? If that's what you want, then it won't be possible (I don't believe) since only the server knows which files are where, and you can't request the contents of a directory from a server using JavaScript.

However if you were using Node.js on a *local* directory, then it could be done. But I don't believe that's your case.

That being said, you have three alternative options:
Name every image file `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, etc. Then use a for loop and get each one using `(i + 1) + ".png"`

If you can't rename the files, but the files are named via user input, you could collect the user's input at the time of file creation and add the name of the newly created file into another file/an array/localStorage so that it could be retrieved later.

If you can't rename the files, but the filenames are also never known to the program that needs them, then you could create an array of all the filenames (manually) and iterate over that to find all the files that you want.

---

Please, somebody let me know if I'm wrong and if there actually is a way to make a request to a server that tells the client all the files in a directory. That seems incredibly unlikely though.

---

Another potential solution just came to mind. You could write a PHP script (or Node.js or any server-side language, really) that scans a directory, creates a list of all the filenames there, and then sends that back over HTTP. Then you could simply make an XMLHttpRequest to that PHP file and have it do the work. How does that sound?

Comment: First sulution sounds like it'd work for me, thanks ^^

Comment: Except i'd need to know the amount of files in the dir automatically

Comment: Wait I think I found a way to do that, thanks

Comment: Ok so i've been working on it, but now theres a new problem.

Comment: I now have a array of paths, but when i try to use a forEach loop to load each image, it gives me this error: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: You could either catch that error with a try block and continue, ignoring the fact that it will make the page "lock up" while the images load, or you could simply use asynchronous XMLHttpRequests and render the images as they load. Is that a problem?

Comment: sorry, im not all that good at coding, could you make an answer for me?

Comment: Nope! I fixed it ^^

Comment: I was using something similar to the first answer, but it cleared the div every time i ran the function, so i just made it so it doesnt clear